# Event Listener issue about video streaming

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, video-streaming, event-listener

I decide to create a video streaming object in a platform. However, I found that my event listener cannot be triggered as the message inside it cannot be displayed. I wonder what problem it is.

`static createStreamingPlane(){
console.log("Stream Test")

```
    const video = document.querySelector("video");
    console.log("Video Acquired")
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata',function(){
        console.log("Function start")
        const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
        console.log("Video Texture loaded")
        var size = 3;
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(size+2, size);
        
        //var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(link);
        console.log('add');
        
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: videoTexture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
        });
        console.log("Material loaded")
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        console.log("Mesh loaded")

        var frame_geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(size + 2.81, size + 0.815);
        frame_geo.name = 'frame_check';
        var frame_text = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(link_f);
        var frame_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: frame_text,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
        });
        var frame_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(frame_geo, frame_mat);
        frame_mesh.position.set(0, -0.15, 0);

        const group = new THREE.Group();
        group.name = 'image with frame';
        mesh.name = 'image';
        frame_mesh.name = 'frame';
        frame_mesh.visible = true;
        frame_mesh.renderOrder = 1;

        group.add(mesh);
        group.add(frame_mesh);
        VRPandaEditor.vrPandaSceneController.currentScene.scene.add(group);

        var newObject1 = new VRPandaObject(group);
        VRPandaEditor.execute(new AddObjectCommand(newObject1));
        VRPandaEditor.vrPandaObjectController.selectObject(newObject1);
    },false);
}`
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code you're showing here do you actually call `createStreamingPlane()`...

Comment: @Brad Sorry for the confusion. The createStreamingPlane() is called later. Now the problem is only "Stream Test" and "Video Acquired" are logged. Other message inside the event listener function are not displayed